# Using a UIPicker for selecting data from a relational database?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

In my sports based app I have a relational database with three separate tables that are linked; country > division > team.

I am considering using a UIPicker for this.  First the user picks the country, then a division, then a team.

Would this require 3 separate pickers, each to be hidden and then revealed upon the selection of each, with an API call to the database after each selection to retrieve the values for the next selection?

Or is there an alternative selection method I should look at?

Comment: One way to represent this hierarchy naturally would be to use to use 3 separate view controllers with table views for the data for each level. Place the first one in a navigation controller and push each subsequent view controller onto the stack.

Comment: The common model for this kind of drill down is to use a tableview.  Think of the Music App where you might go artist, album song.  Doing this with a picker could be strange.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar with countries, state/provinces, and schools

```
struct Location {

    let countries: [Country]
    let states: [Country: [State]]
    let schools: [State: [School]]
}
```

Basically I queried the API to create this `struct` then had three `UITextFields` with an `inputView` to a `UIPicker` then in each of my `UIPickerViewDelegate` methods I had switch statements that typecast the `pickerView` to the appropriate one and did my logic there.

Based on this `struct` you can see that `Country` was a key to an array of `State` structs and `State` was a key to an array of `Schools`.

*Note*: You gotta get your custom structs to conform to Hashable to get this kind of funcitonality